# Missing column when appending csv files using excel power query

Tags: excel, csv, append, powerquery

I’m using excel power query to append four CSV files. Each file has the same five columns. However, the resulting combined file is missing the last column of data. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: A problem with your code or data that you have not accounted for in the appending.

Comment: Take out the ,columns= part

Comment: this probably needs some sample data that people can use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the solution was to remove the *"Columns=37,"* from the below statement. This allows for all columns to be retrieved into the M query, not just the first X columns. Thanks everyone!

```
= Csv.Document(#"Select File",[Delimiter=",", Columns=37, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
```